# Merging two datasets on a column in common

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use a dataset which includes some useful information to create a new column including those information, whether they were included.

df1

```
Info    User    Year
24      user1   2012
0       user2   2012
12      user3   2010
24.5    user4   2011
24      user5   2012
```

Users here are unique (no duplicates)

df2

```
Date              User      Year      Note
2012-02-13        user1     2012       NA
2012-01-11        user4     2011       Paid
2012-02-13        user1     2012       Need review
2012-02-14        user3     2010       NA
2012-02-13        user2     2012       NA
2012-02-11        user2     2012       Need review
```

Since there is a column in common, I am considering to join these tables on User. I tried as follows:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['User'])
```

but the output is different from that I would expect, i.e.

(expected output)

```
Date              User      Year      Note              Info
2012-02-13        user1     2012       NA                24
2012-01-11        user4     2011       Paid              24.5
2012-02-13        user1     2012       Need review       24
2012-02-14        user3     2010       NA                12
2012-02-13        user2     2012       NA                0
2012-02-11        user2     2012       Need review       0
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong in my code above?

Comment: what did you expect, though?

Comment: I showed you what I would expect. It is the last table. I added a note to highlight the expected output in case it was not clear. Thanks

Comment: then what was the actual result?

Comment: a few rows. I did not add any other filter.

Comment: please just show it.

Comment: I really do not understand why people downvote a question that has data to use and code I tried and expected output. Seriously, I cannot understand people. Next time, then, close the question. It would be better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do two things: 1) Specify the minimum columns required (`[['Info', 'User']]`) and `how='left'`, so you don't merge another `Year` column in. You had the dataframes flipped around in your merge:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1[['Info', 'User']], on=['User'], how='left')

Out[1]: 
         Date   User  Year         Note  Info
0  2012-02-13  user1  2012          NaN  24.0
1  2012-01-11  user4  2011         Paid  24.5
2  2012-02-13  user1  2012  Need review  24.0
3  2012-02-14  user3  2010          NaN  12.0
4  2012-02-13  user2  2012          NaN   0.0
5  2012-02-11  user2  2012  Need review   0.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot David. I was completely wrong as I thought inner join was the right way to merge them. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: No problem @LucaDiMauro . In my experience a `left` merge is the most common merge. A `right` merge does the same exact thing as well if you switch the order of the dataframes in `merge`, but most people do `left` merges. I rarely see people do a `right` merge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `RIGHT INNER JOIN`

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', on=['User'])
```